# Having to commit all files through GitHub Desktop every time on each computer

Tags: github, synchronization, repository, github-desktop

I have been using GitHub desktop on my computer at work, in which the repositories are saved in a OneDrive folder.

I recently bought a new laptop and all my repositories are already available through OneDrive. I tried loading them into GitHub desktop by clicking "Add existing repository from your Hard Drive" and indicating the path to it.

By the folder name, GitHub desktop is able to recognize that this is an already existing repository (and not a new one). However, all the files need to be committed again, as if GitHub interprets that they are not exactly the same as the ones currently saved online.

If I commit them again through my new laptop, the same issue will appear when I try to open GitHub Desktop on my work computer.

I have tried checking OneDrive synching issue, but that is not the problem. Files are identical and GitHub indicates that there are **no content changes**. [image] Could that be caused by the fact they have different paths on each machine? Any fixes?

Comment: Did the file permissions change? What does `git diff main^!` show?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Brian. Unfortunately, I don't know how to verify that. Since I am using the Desktop version, I don't use the terminal (which is where I assume I should input the `git diff main^!`)